# WAV plays from file, does not play directly from URL

Tags: android, audio, media-player, wav

I have a URL that returns a 8-bit PCM, mono, 8 kHz WAV sound. When I try to play that URL via Android's MediaPlayer class, I get an error and the following in LogCat:

```
09-29 17:36:40.710: ERROR/PlayerDriver(562): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info PVMFFailure
09-29 17:36:40.730: ERROR/MediaPlayer(25215): error (1, -1)
```

The content type that the URL returns is audio/x-wav. I The error occurs after calling prepareAsync():

```
String uri = "http://whatever";
s_Player.setDataSource(uri);
s_Player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
s_Player.prepareAsync();
```

When I replace `uri` with a file path to the same sound stored in the filesystem, it plays fine. Playing the URL in the Android browser works. So it must be me somehow misusing MediaPlayer. Any ideas, please?

EDIT: it's on the emulator (for now), so permissions are not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't request Internet permission in the manifest???

Comment: On the emulator it's not an issue.

Comment: Whether or not you are using the emulator, you must correctly specify `<uses-permission>` in the manifest file. In your case, you should ensure that you've specified `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`.